# Why in some cases when the player is moving to the left he is leaving in 1.5 distance the grid area?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

public class DirsFinder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public float playerMoveSpeed = 1f;
    public float playerRotationSpeed = 0.5f;
    public float distanceToTravel = 1.5f;
    public bool randomDir = true;

    private Transform start;
    private Transform end;
    private GridGenerator gridgenerator;
    private List<Vector3> possibleDirections = new List<Vector3>();
    private Vector3 selectedDirection;
    private float m_distanceTraveled = 0f;
    private List<Vector3> visitedList = new List<Vector3>();
    private List<Vector3> toBeVisitedList = new List<Vector3>();
    private Vector3 playerPosition;

    public void FindDir()
    {
        gridgenerator = GetComponent<GridGenerator>();
        GenerateStartEnd();
        FindDirections();
        m_distanceTraveled = 0;
    }

    private void FindDirections()
    {
        possibleDirections = new List<Vector3>();
        playerPosition = player.localPosition;
        m_distanceTraveled = 0;

        if (playerPosition.x > 0)
        {
            // can go left
            possibleDirections.Add(Vector3.left);
        }

        if (playerPosition.x + gridgenerator.spaceBetweenBlocks < gridgenerator.gridWidth * gridgenerator.spaceBetweenBlocks)
        {
            // can go right
            possibleDirections.Add(Vector3.right);
        }

        if (playerPosition.z > 0)
        {
            // can go backward
            possibleDirections.Add(Vector3.back);
        }


        if (playerPosition.z + gridgenerator.spaceBetweenBlocks < gridgenerator.gridHeight * gridgenerator.spaceBetweenBlocks)
        {
            // can go forward
            possibleDirections.Add(Vector3.forward);
        }

        if (randomDir == true)
        {
            selectedDirection = possibleDirections[Random.Range(0, possibleDirections.Count)];
        }
        player.forward = selectedDirection;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (m_distanceTraveled < distanceToTravel)
        {
            Vector3 oldPosition = player.position;
            player.position += selectedDirection * Time.deltaTime * playerMoveSpeed;
            m_distanceTraveled += Vector3.Distance(oldPosition, player.position);
        }

        if (m_distanceTraveled >= distanceToTravel)
        {
            FindDirections();
        }
    }

    private List<Vector3> GenerateStartEnd()
    {
        GameObject walls = GameObject.Find("Walls");
        List<Transform> wallsParents = new List<Transform>();
        List<Vector3> startEndPos = new List<Vector3>();

        foreach (Transform child in walls.transform)
        {
            wallsParents.Add(child);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            wallsParents.Remove(wallsParents[Random.Range(0, wallsParents.Count)]);
        }

        var childsWall0 = wallsParents[0].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>().ToList();
        var childsWall1 = wallsParents[1].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>().ToList();
        childsWall0.RemoveAt(0);
        childsWall1.RemoveAt(0);

        start = childsWall0[Random.Range(0, childsWall0.Count)];
        player.position = start.position;
        end = childsWall1[Random.Range(0, childsWall1.Count)];
        end.tag = "End";
        startEndPos.Add(start.position);
        startEndPos.Add(end.position);

        start.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        end.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;

        return startEndPos;
    }
}
```

In the method FindDirections i assign the player to be facing to the selected random direction:

```
player.forward = selectedDirection;
```

Then in the Update i'm moving the player to specific distance each time 1.5f And checking when the player traveled 1.5 distance call FindDirections again and over again. I checked with a break point it keep getting back to the FindDirections and getting a new random direction.

But in some cases when the player is walking to the left since it's random i saw it on the left side only so far didn't see it yet on the right side of the grid.

But when he is getting to the left in some cases he is keep moving by 1.5 out of the grid left wall out of the grid.

[image: out of grid left wall]

In the screenshot two cases where the player left the grid area on the left then he walk on this area and then back to the grid area.

It started when i started to move the player with the limit distance of 1.5 and the travel distance.

Not sure why it happen.

Comment: It's not only left it's in all directions that he is moving and sometimes leaving the grid area.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be caused by floating-point precision.
This piece of code

```
 if (playerPosition.x > 0)
```

…evaluates true if playerPosition.x is a small value such as 0.000001.
You could avoid this by using small margin in comparison.

```
 const float margin = 0.001f;
 ...
 if (playerPosition.x - margin > 0f) // (pos.x - bounds.leftx) < margin
```

Better approach would be to use integers as grip positions.

Another thing is that you update player.position in Update() but use player.localPosition in FindDirections(). I’m not sure if this is intended.
(However, if the player transform has no parent, localPosition is same as position.)

EDIT: You could also force the player position to nearest multiple of 1.5f before setting a new direction:

```
if (m_distanceTraveled >= distanceToTravel)
{
// round x and z to nearest multiple of distanceToTravel
var tmpPos = player.position;
tmpPos.x = Mathf.Round(player.position.x / distanceToTravel) * distanceToTravel;
tmpPos.z = Mathf.Round(player.position.z / distanceToTravel) * distanceToTravel;
player.position = tmpPos;
FindDirections();
}
```

Comment: What margin value did you use? I inserted debug print in FindDirections() and noticed that position.x values can be 1.510146 or 1.48392 (near 1.5) or 0.00814414 (near 0) so there is pretty big imprecision in position.